# How can a unit step function be differentiable??

Tags: functions, special-functions, signal-processing

Recently, I am taking a Signal & System course at my college. In all of the signal & system textbooks I have read, we see that it is written " When we differentiate a Unit Step Function, we get an Impulse function. " But as far as I have read, a unit step function is a piece-wise linear function as well as it is a continuous function but it is non differentiable. My question is that how can a non differentiable function be differentiated to obtain the impulse function?? Where is the contradiction.....

I am confused...would be happy if anybody helps...

[For more info,you can see this link](http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Transient/TransInputs/TransImpulseTime.html)

Comment: It's not the classical derivative, but the distributional derivative. The so-called "Impulse function" is not a function. It's a (shifted, maybe) Dirac distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative of the unit step function (or Heaviside function) is the Dirac delta, which is a generalized function (or a distribution). [This wikipedia page on the Dirac delta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) is quite informative on the matter.

One way to define the Dirac delta function is as a measure $\delta$ on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
\delta(A) = \begin{cases}
0 &: \text{ if } 0 \notin A \\
1 &: \text{ if } 0 \in A
\end{cases}
$$
Then one can write down precisely what is meant by the expression
$$
\int fd \delta = f(0)
$$

Answer (score 1):

In a "practical sense", it comes from
$$
\Theta\left(x\right) = \int_{-\infty}^{x}\delta\left(x'\right)\,{\rm d}x'
$$

It's is quite useful but you have to handle carefully as, for example, @Prahlad Vaidyanathan already pointed out.